# Java String from int concat with minus sign

Tags: java, string

I want my program to concat String variables (Date->int->String) but with a minus (-) sign between the Strings that I want to merge. For example: `StringA + "-" + StringB` or `StringA.concat("-").concat(StringB)`. But if `String a="100"` and `StringB="200"` the operation would return me "-100" instead of "200-100".
Why is this? Does String somehow converts Strings to int and then executes mathematical operations? No sense.

Code:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
int sYear = dt.getYear();
int sMonth = dt.getMonthOfYear();
String minDate = null;
String y = Integer.toString(sYear);
String m = Integer.toString(sMonth);
minDate = y + "-" + m + "-01"; //or y.concat("-").concat(m).concat("-01");
```

The example I have above returns 1715.

Comment: This is probably what you want... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4216745/java-string-to-date-conversion

Comment: Hint: you never ever want to format dates manually. As you are re-inventing the wheel, and worse: you will get it wrong. Even when you work hard for half a week; and your code passes all your tests; it will be wrong (if you attempt to create some "generic" solution that works for all kinds of dates).

Comment: I have to pass value to Javascript form as string. Example, today is 2016-04-22. I need to pass 2016-03-01 to form. I get year that I need, month that I need and day that I need. How to combine 20016, 03 and 01 in String to get "2016-03-01"?

Answer (score 1):

While you should definitely follow @Tunaki's advise on how to format a `Date`, I think the real problem lies elsewhere.

```
System.out.println("03".concat("-").concat("10").concat("-01"));
```

Here the output will be `03-10-01` and *not* `-8` (your example gives a similar output).

You mentioned in one of your comments:

> I have to pass value to Javascript form as string.

I guess that's where the real problem lies. For example, if the resulting *JavaScript* ends up looking something like this:

```
var myDate = 2016-03-01 ;
```

The expression will be evaluated and `myDate` will end up as a number with the value `2012`. You will have to make sure you're passing a string and not a number.

Answer (score 0):

The right answer is:
Java

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
LocalDate prevMonthFirstDay = today.minusMonths(1).withDayOfMonth(1);
LocalDate prevMonthLastDay = prevMonthFirstDay.plusMonths(1).minusDays(1);
```

Javascript

```
var f = document.forms['SearchForm'];
f.startdate.value = "<%=prevMonthFirstDay.toString()%>"
f.enddate.value = "<%=prevMonthLastDay.toString()%>"
```

Special thanks to all those who "helped" me putting minuses.